# Creating a random number generator using a for-loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, random, numbers, generator

I have a homework question where I have to make a random number generator using a for loop that gives me a random numbers 'n' number of times. this is what i have so far.

```
import random
def randNum(n):
    myList = []
    randomNumber = int random.random() * 10)
    myList.append(randomNumber)
    for  in range (1,10):
        return myList
```

Any pointers? I'm very new to coding and would love to know how I can improve/make things simpler. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to post a complete solution that you can just copy and paste.  I think programming is like playing a musical instrument, you can't learn it by just watching somebody else do it.  Instead, let me point out places where you need to fix something.

Your first three lines are fine, although you never end up using the argument `n`.

Your problem description doesn't say that you need to generate integers, nor that they should be values in the range [0,9] (which is what you'll get if you multiply numbers between 0 and 1 by 10 and apply `int()`, which rounds down).  You also have unbalanced parentheses.  A trick which dates back to the days of punched cards is to start at zero and add one for every left parenthesis, subtract one for each right.  If you don't get back to zero at the end of the line, or you ever dip negative in the middle, you have a balanced paren problem.

You don't actually need the variable `randomNumber`, you can just put the expression which created the value into your `myList.append()`'s parentheses.  However, some folks like to create the extra variable for clarity, or to separate the statements for debugging purposes to help isolate the location of any problems, so keeping or ditching the variable is a matter of taste/preference.

Your biggest problem is that you're only generating and storing a `randomNumber` once.  You want to place that logic in a `for` loop, controlled by the argument `n`.

Your last two lines attempt to `return myList`, which contains one element, 9 times.  You can only `return` once from a function, so your first attempt will end things.  Don't put a simple `return` statement in a loop, it's pointless unless the `return` is conditional.

Finally, a `for` loop needs an index variable, i.e., something between the keywords `for` and `in`.  It should be a variable such as `i` or `j` or `loop_index` if you plan to use the current iteration's index value within the loop.  If you don't actually need to use the index, use an underscore: `for _ in range(1,10):`.  And last but not least, `range(1,10)` iterates over the values 1 through 9, the upper value is *exclusive*.  A common way to iterate 10 times would be `for i in range(10):`, the lower limit is zero if omitted.  This will iterate 10 times, yielding values 0 through 9 which can be accessed via `i` within the loop.